# How to save several times without overwriting the file

Tags: matlab, save, overwrite

I have a problem with my code in matlab.
I have a matrix C (make reshape as a vector) and I want to save several C vectors to one file. This is my code

```
wynik = reshape(C',1,[]);
    fileID = fopen('Desktop\test.txt','r');
    fileID_out = fopen('Desktop\test_out.txt','r');

  fprintf(fileID, '%d \r', wynik);
  fprintf(fileID, '\n');
  fprintf(fileID_out, ' %d \r\n', 2);
 end
```

I made a loop at the begin so in a console I have for example 2 different matrix, but using this code it overwrite my file and  I save only the last one vector. I would like to have sth like this (shorter example)
A = [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6 ]  ( first loop)
A = [7 8 9; 1 2 3 ] ( second loop)
In my file(with spaces between values and with \n on the end of line) :

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 1 2 3
```

Comment: Read the docs ;) https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html#btrnibn-1-permission

Comment: Either append to a file (see the docs @AnderBiguri linked) or create a new file every loop iteration.

Comment: If you're saving a matix, use `save` instead... writing to a text file isn't optimal unless you have to

Comment: The code makes no sense, you are opening the files for reading, and then write to them. I'm sure you must be getting errors there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example in your question is quite unclear because you ask about **saving** data but all your file opening instructions use only **reading** permissions.

I'll give you an example which works for your 2nd (shorter) example because it is clearer what you are trying to achieve.

I strongly recommend to read the documentation for:

- [`fopen`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html), and particularly the usage of the parameter `permission`.
- [`fprintf`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) the the parameter `formatSpec` will be useful.

---

Armed with that documentation, you will realise that to write to an existing file already containing data is called ***append*** to the file. So for your usage: The first time you create the file, open it with the permission `'w'`. For all the other time you want to **add** (=***append***) something to the file, open it with the permission `'a'`, then write normally to it.

Your second example in code:

```
%% Initial data
A = [1,2,3;4,5,6];

%% prepare format specifier for a complete line
nElem = numel(A) ;
baseformat = '%d ' ;                                % base number format
writeFormat = repmat( baseformat , 1 , nElem ) ;    % replicated "nElem" times
writeFormat = [writeFormat(1:end-1) '\n'] ;         % remove last trailing space and replace by newline
% => now writeFormat = "%d %d %d %d %d %d\n"

%% Open the file the first time to write the first line
% permission 'w' => Open or create new file for writing. Discard existing contents, if any.
fidout = fopen('myfileout.txt', 'w') ; 
fprintf( fidout , writeFormat , A(:) ) ;
fclose(fidout) ;

%% Now let's write 5 additional lines
for iLine=1:5
    % simulate a different matrix [A]
    A = A + nElem ; % A will continue counting

    % permission 'a' => Open or create new file for writing. Append data to the end of the file.
    fidout = fopen('myfileout.txt', 'a') ; 
    fprintf( fidout , writeFormat , A(:) ) ;
    fclose(fidout) ;
end
```

Which should give you the file `myfileout.txt`, containing:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36
```